# The number of possible subsets of the set {1,{3,4}}?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I found this question in an exam and my answer was 8(=2^3) which was evaluated as wrong. Can anyone provide their inputs on the why the no. of subsets is only 4 where as the number of elements is 3.

Thanks.

Comment: Note that {3,4} is a single element , not 2.

Comment: You recieved 2 answers to your question. Is any of them what you needed? If so, you should upvote all the useful answers and accept the answer that is most useful to you.

Answer (score 3):

- If $A$ has $k$ elements, then the number of possible subsets of $A$ is $2^k$.
- Your set has $2$ elements
- Therefore, your set has $2^2=4$ possible subsets.

In particular, the $4$ subsets of your set are:

$$\varnothing, \{1\}, \{\{3,4\}\}, \{1,\{3,4\}\}$$

Answer (score 1):

One can consider the problem more abstractly by taking the set $A=\{a,b\}$. It has the power set $2^A= \{\emptyset, \{a\},\{b\},\{a,b\}\}$. In your case, $a=1$ and $b=\{3,4\}$.